# Rendering a TabNavigator in Storybook

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, storybook

I want to use Storybook.js to mock up a page that utilizes createMaterialTopTabNavigator(). However I can't render the material Tab because the output of the function is not actually a react component. So when I directly tried `<TabNavigator />` it threw an invariant violation that "navigation" was missing. The only work-around I found was using createAppContainer() around the TabNavigator. But I know that it is bad practice to use more than one navigator. **Is there any way to render a react navigator element without needing the navigation container?**

This is my current working code for the storybook:

```js
const tabConfiguration = {
  Old: {
    screen: OldProductsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Old"
    }
  },
  New: {
    screen: NewProductsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "New"
    }
  }
};
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(tabConfiguration);

storiesOf('Test', module)
  .add('Initial', () => {
    const TAB = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
    return (
      <TAB / >
    );
  })

;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that it is bad practice to use more than one navigator. Is there any way to render a react navigator element without needing the navigation container?

It's bad practice to do that in an app. But since you're using Storybook where each container is in like its own independent app, this is totally fine.